# Comparing vertices

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I have a list of graph edges.  E.g.

```
{"woods" <-> "woody", "aback" <-> "alack", "tummy" <-> "yummy", "tumor" <-> "tutor"}
```

How can I compare the vertices to extract the same letters?

Coming from another programming language, I know how to do this using a nested loop and by comparing the characters, but this seems remarkably inappropriate.

Comment: What do you mean by extract the same letter? Can you give us a desired output?

Comment: Please describe more precisely how comparing should be done, what is the expected result and assumed input (sam lenght? etc)

Comment: @Wjx, desired output for the following example is  `{"wood", "aack", "ummy", "tuor"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One liner:

```
LongestCommonSequence @@@ {"woods" <-> "woody", "aback" <-> "alack", "tummy" <-> "yummy", "tumor" <-> "tutor"}
```

> {"wood", "aack", "ummy", "tuor"}

`LongestCommonSubsequence` extract things for each pair and `@@@` apply this on level 1.

```
UndirectedEdge @@ Transpose@Cases[SequenceAlignment[##], _List] & @@@ {"woods" <-> "woody", "aback" <-> "alack", "tummy" <-> "yummy", "tumor" <-> "tutor"}
```

> {{"s"} <-> {"y"}, {"b"} <-> {"l"}, {"t"} <-> {"y"}, {"m"} <-> {"t"}}